# Firebase hosting index.html only shows when specified in the URL `/index.html`, default/home page "Site not found"

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting

In my firebase URL, when I go to https://example.web.app, it says "Site not found" from Firebase.

But if I would go to https://example.web.app/index.html, the URL would work and it would show the `index.html` page.

How would I make it so it would point to the default page aka home page, instead of me having to redirect to the `index.html` page?

`firebase.json`:

```json
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`dist/index.html` exists.
`dist` directory is used for the `public` hosting.

`index.html` works fine when I redirect to `https://example.web.app/index.html`, but doesn't work when I go to `https://example.web.app`, how would I fix that?

The URL is just an "example," to try to explain to you guys. This is not the ACTUAL URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to contact Firebase customer support and ask help from them.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the url https://your-website-name.firebaseapp.com, you will find it to work but not the https://your-website-name.web.app.

**To solve this problem**, run the following command line code:
curl -X PURGE https://your-website-name.web.app.

*I had the same issue and got this help from the Google Support Team.*